# show custom table data in grid in magento

Tags: magento

Hello Please let me know how i can show custom table data in grid

Here is my code please help me.

protected function _prepareCollection(){

```
 //$collection = Mage::getModel('multivendor/advertisement_advertisementproduct')->getCollection();
//print_r($collection);  die("worigns");
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
 $sql        = "Select * from adv_spaces";
 $rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql); //fetchRow($sql), fetchOne($sql),...
// Zend_Debug::dump($rows);
 $this->setCollection($connection);       
return parent::_prepareCollection();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

magento direction query

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
 $sql        = "Select * from adv_spaces";
 $rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

should not works. For a grid collection you need proper `Magento Model Resource Collection`.Just like

```
$collection = Mage::getRescourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection');
```

[Please study here](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/)